# "URL blocked" message. Meta tag solution not working

Tags: facebook, url, button, facebook-like, blocked

I've added an iframe like button to my website but whenever someone clicks on it they get the "URL could not be liked because it's been blocked" message. I tried adding this tag

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="my facebook id" />
```

but it makes no difference.

My web is hosted at 000 web hosting. I first set their domain (brunez.net63.net)to be the one associated with the button but I got the error message. After that, I replaced that URL with a dot.tk one (brunez.tk) that redirects to my web site. I managed to hit the like button succesfully once, but now, if anyone else hits it, the error message shows up.

Adding the meta tag mentioned above is the only solution I've found so far, but it doesn't work. Some people suggest that I contact the developers group, but the only section related to assistance in that page took me here. If the URL has actually been blocked (I don't see a reason), is there a way to unblock it?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook provides [a tool](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal) that will analyze the content of the page for a specified link.

You can request Facebook to remove the block by going here: https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal